# Using $ over Parentheses Example

Tags: haskell

Looking at `liftA2`:

```
ghci> :t liftA2
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

I can produce an `Either (a, a)`:

```
ghci> liftA2 (\x y -> (x, y)) (Right 100) (Right 1)
Right (100,1)
```

But I get a compile-time error if I use `$`:

```
ghci> liftA2 (\x y -> (x, y)) $ Right 100 $ Right 20

<interactive>:23:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `Either a1 b1 -> f t'
                with actual type `Either a0 b0'
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: f t1 -> f (t, t1) (bound at <interactive>:23:1)
    The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
    but its type `Either a0 b0' has none
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `Right 100 $ Right 20'
    In the expression: liftA2 (\ x y -> (x, y)) $ Right 100 $ Right 20
```

Why can't I use `$` for this example to get the same result as with parentheses?

Comment: Because `$` is right-associative. `Right 100 (Right 20)` doesn't type check.

Comment: FYI you can use `(,)` instead of your lambda: `liftA2 (,) (Right 100) (Right 1)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thats because

```
liftA2 (\x y -> (x, y)) $ Right 100 $ Right 20
```

Is equal to

```
liftA2 (\x y -> (x, y)) ( Right 100 ( Right 20 ))
```

---

You are trying to shove an additional argument into the `Right` constructor (takes one argument, but type has none) and your liftA2 is missing one.